# Launch app from SD card on Symbian

Tags: symbian

I'm not very familiar with the Symbian platform -- last time I poked around was a few years ago, and since then things have probably changed.

Anyway -- we're studying the possibility of writing an app for Symbian which we'd like to be able to distribute, in addition to internet, on SD cards (for business reasons). So, does Symbian support installing apps from SD card in a straightforward way? Even better would be if there is a way to offer the user to install the app automatically upon SD card insertion (there's a mechanism like that on Windows Mobile which allows you to autolaunch an app placed in a specific location on SD card upon SD card insertion)

Also, if anybody has any info about support for similar mechanism on any other platform, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation from memory card is explained on Forum Nokia: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_guide_for_pre-installed_applications

You cannot auto-run an application on installation when it is installed in this manner, however.